# How to Disable the Vue component (div-tag)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am trying to disable the VUE component based on the user access settings. Now, I am able to hide the component from the UI, but after every **re-render**, the component is getting **active**. I don't just want to **hide the component**; I want to **prevent** the user from **clicking the component**. I couldn't find the exact solution to my problem. Thank you in advance.

This is the route and beforeEach route condition:

```
 {
    path: "/settings/overview",
    name: "SettingsOverview",
    component: PageSettingsOverview,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
      showComponent: true,
      componentAccessPermissions: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
    },
  },

**beforeEach**

 const currentLogUser = store.getters["auth/currentUser"];
    if (
      currentLogUser !== null &&
      to?.meta?.componentAccessPermissions !== undefined
    ) {
      for (let i = 0; i < currentLogUser.teams.length; i++) {
        const team = currentLogUser.teams[i];
        const valPermissions = team.permissions
          .filter((item) => {
            return to.meta.componentAccessPermissions.includes(
              item.permissionType
            );
          })
          .map((item) => {
            return item.permissionType;
          });
        const allowAccess = to.meta.componentAccessPermissions.every((i) =>
          valPermissions.includes(i)
        );
        if (!allowAccess) {
          to.meta.showComponent = false;
        } else {
          to.meta.showComponent = true;
        }
      }
    }
```

VueFile:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-4" v-if='$route.meta.showComponent' @click.prevent>
        <router-link class="card" to="/administration" >
          <div class="card-img-top">
            <i class="hi hi-people" />
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Teams & Users</h5>
          </div>
        </router-link>
      </div>
```

Comment: Disabling, preventing and hiding are 3 different actions. Please be clearer about what you want to achieve - perhaps by using an image.

Comment: Disable would be a better option. Will you able to help?

Comment: Do you have server side authentication as well?

Comment: Because if you just disable in the front-end this can easily be bypassed through inspect element.

Comment: Actually, I did server side authentication. Now, I just need to disable the Component instead of redirecting to **not found page**

Comment: To prevent people from clicking the component you can use `pointer-events: none` in CSS for people who don't have access

Comment: You seem to be using bootstrap - so you can use the `pe-none` bootstrap class.

Comment: You can also go a step further and display an overlay over the component and toggle it using `v-if` when the user isn't authenticated

Comment: It seems like pe-none working, actually in beforeEach route-guard I wrote showComponent has false, if user do not have access. Can you look at the code and let me know any changes are required?

Comment: I don't know what your authentication scheme is, but it looks ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toggle pointer-events in CSS to prevent the user from interacting with your component;

```html
<div :class="`col-12 col-md-4 ${$route.meta.showComponent ? 'pe-none' : ''}`">
    <router-link class="card" to="/administration" >
        <div class="card-img-top">
            <i class="hi hi-people" />
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Teams & Users</h5>
        </div>
    </router-link>
</div>
```

If you don't have bootstrap;

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-4" :style="`${$route.meta.showComponent ? 'pointer-events: none' : ''}`">
    <router-link class="card" to="/administration" >
        <div class="card-img-top">
            <i class="hi hi-people" />
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Teams & Users</h5>
        </div>
    </router-link>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working. I do not know that we can write condition inside the :class. Thanks Bernard.

Comment: It works fine but after every re-render, the component is becoming active and I have no idea why the component is getting active after reloading.

Comment: You need to debug it by checking what the value for $route.meta.showComponent is

Comment: After re-rendering, showComponent takes the boolean value from meta. That is the issue, is there any way to resolve the issue?

Comment: That is the intended effect. You need to see why the value is changing

Comment: Your initial question is answered. Try to debug and see what is wrong yourself and if you still have problems create a separate question and people can help you with your separate problem if it persists

Comment: I have no idea but I will try to find it. Thank you Bernard

Answer (score 0):

Return false from `beforeEach` function to cancel the routing, this way, user won't be able to load that component if it's managed by vue-router.

[Documentation with examples](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards)